# Add element at the start of array and delete at the end numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the best way to add a new element at the start of numpy array and delete the last element of this array ?

I used code like this :

```
tmp = np.array([1,2,3])
print(tmp)
tmp = np.insert(tmp,0,0)
tmp = np.delete(tmp,-1)
print(tmp)
```

So I got what I wanted:

```
[1 2 3]
[0 1 2]
```

But I suspect that there is a better way to do this.

Comment: That's not so bad for doing it once, but it sounds like there may be a better way to do things in the context of your overall algorithm.

Comment: For efficiency (perf, memory), I would think`np.concatenate(([0], tmp[:-1]))`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A cleaner way to do what you are doing:

```
tmp = np.insert(tmp[0:-1], 0, 0)
```

or

```
tmp = np.append([0], tmp[0:-1])
```

or

```
tmp = np.concatenate(([0], tmp[0:-1]))
```

If you want to insert at a specific position in the array then `.insert` is clean approach but if your requirements are to add an element at 0th position(or end) then concatenate might be more efficient.

A simple timeit check reveals `2.07 µs` per loop for concatenate, `5.47 µs` per loop for append and `12.7` µs per loop for insert(this is not the perfect way of measuring time but it gives a rough estimate)

Comment: Thanks for you answer !