# How can I add to the end of a numpy array and remove from the beginning?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with shape: `(1, 100)`, which is:

```
[[1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 55.]]
```

I want to add something (say a number like `123`) to the end and remove the first element, so that I will have:

```
[[2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 55. 123.]]
```

Which retains the original shape `(1, 100)`

I am trying:

```
x_pred = np.append(x_pred, next_index, axis=1)
```

(`x_pred` is a `(1, 100)` array and `next_index` is a scalar)

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `something`?

Comment: A number, like `123`

Comment: You can check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517485/add-element-at-the-start-of-array-and-delete-at-the-end-numpy Hope that can help you.

Comment: So something like `np.r_[a,123][1:]`

Comment: Is `x_pred` the (1,100) array? is `next_index` a scalar?

Comment: Yes. `x_pred` is a `(1,100)` array and `next_index` is a scalar

Comment: Related: [NumPy append vs concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932101/numpy-append-vs-concatenate)

Comment: Also related: [when should i use hstack/vstack vs append vs concatenate vs column_stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356442/when-should-i-use-hstack-vstack-vs-append-vs-concatenate-vs-column-stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
x_pred = np.zeros((1,100))
x_pred = np.insert(x_pred, x_pred.size, 123, 1)
x_pred = np.delete(x_pred, 0, axis=1)
```

x_pred prints:

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
        123.]])
```

with size `100`

---

**Below does not work for 2 dimensional array but is correct for a 1 dimensional array:**

Using numpy insert you can do this

```
import numpy as np
tmp = np.array([0,1,2,3])
tmp = np.insert(tmp[1:], tmp.size-1, 123)
# [  1,   2,   3, 123]
```

or more like your example

```
import numpy as np
tmp = np.array([0,0,0,0])
tmp = np.insert(tmp[1:], tmp.size-1, 123)
# [  0,   0,   0, 123]
```

In `np.insert()` the first parameter is the array to insert into, the second is the index where you want to insert, and the third is the value to insert.

The `tmp[1:]` just says everything except the first element (i.e. the 0th elem) up to the end.

```
x_pred = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0,])
x_pred = np.insert(x_pred[1:], x_pred.size-1, 123)
```

`x_pred` prints:

```
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 123])
```

and 
`x_pred.size` prints `100`

Comment: I get `IndexError: index 99 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: Even with the `tmp.size-1` index?

Comment: Yes, I have `x_pred = np.insert(x_pred[1:], x_pred.size-1, next_index)` and `x_pred.size` is `100`

Comment: What is next index? is this being used inside a loop?

Comment: Yes, this is being used inside a loop. `next_index` is a float

Comment: I see, I missed that you had a 1x100 two dimensional array and not a one dimensional array

Comment: It is fixed now

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `roll`.

```
a = np.zeros((1,10))

#roll and replace
a[0] = np.roll(a[0],-1)
a[0][-1] = new_value
```

Answer (score 1):

*Append* the scalar as a list in a list so that it *has the same number of dimensions*:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0,1,2,3]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
>>> q = 123
>>> np.append(a[:,1:],[[q]], axis=1)
array([[  1,   2,   3, 123]])
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> b = np.array([[q]])
>>> np.concatenate([a[:,1:],b], 1)
array([[  1,   2,   3, 123]])
>>> np.concatenate([a[:,1:],[[q]]], 1)
array([[  1,   2,   3, 123]])
```